# Emails not getting through Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am building a process to send emails from my application. I signed up for a Office 365 org in Azure to test this. In my App registration, I granted the following permissions. The admin consent has been granted for these permissions.

[image: Configured permissions]

Next I wrote this code, which is based off a github project.

```
        using Microsoft.Graph;
    using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.UI;

namespace DemoOutlookMail
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void send_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            const string tenantId = "APP REGISTRATION TENANT ID";
            const string redirectUri = "https://localhost:44316/";
            const string clientSecret = "APP REGISTRATION SECRET";
            const string clientId = "APP REGISTRATION CLIENT ID";

            const string AuthorityFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
            IConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient;
            daemonClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority(string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId))
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(daemonClient,"Mail.Send");

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            SendEmail(graphClient);
        }

        private void SendEmail(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                        {
                        new Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "AdeleV@testariesllc.onmicrosoft.com"
                            }
                        }
            },
                CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "AlexW@testariesllc.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var saveToSentItems = false;
            try
            {
                graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, saveToSentItems).Request().PostAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Label1.Text = e.Message;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code runs but doesn't send any emails, doesn't throw any exceptions. **What am I missing?**
The original github project is https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp

Answer (score 0):

Because your using Application permission the /me endpoint is supported

> Calling the /me endpoint requires a signed-in user and therefore a delegated permission.
> Application permissions are not supported when using the /me endpoint.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

So in your code you need to specify the user your going to be sending as it should be an easy fix eg

```
 graphClient.Users["user@domain.com"].SendMail(message, saveToSentItems).Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: I did try this approach, but no luck yet. I have a domain created in Azure for testing this out. I have tried to put in a user's email address, but still don't see any mails getting sent.

Comment: The pre-reqs for this would be the user your entering would need to have a licensed Exchange Online Mailbox. (eg they should be able to logon to outlook.office365.com and send email). These Graph endpoints are giving you access to the Exchange Online back-end they aren't a generic SMTP type endpoint.